# Effect of offensive speech online on grad student life

Tags: graduate-school, advisor, professorship

I have a friend who has been accepted to grad school who posts stuff on line on social media that would offend many people.  The person is not racist, homophobic, or anti-semitic but someone reading it might think so.  Do you think this will have any effect on their life as a grad student, working with an advisor/professors or future career?  The person just enjoys being provocative and apparently doesn't like to self censor.

Comment: What country is your friend going to grad school in? I suspect this is something that varies tremendously across different cultures.

Comment: _The person is not racist, homophobic, or anti-semitic, but..._ [Hmmmmm](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=i'm+not+racist%2C+but+.+.+.).

Comment: Some people like to be offensive just to be offensive; they even may get very far, and without hurting them (see pres*hack, cough*ident elections). However, for most, the internet exposes you to everyone on this planet as direct neighbour. Traditionally, one needed only one difficult neighbour to poison the atmosphere for, say, ~30 people around them. Now, any sensitive/righteous/oversensitive/self-righteous person from the planet becomes one's neighbour and a potential career destroyer. Freedom of speech is accompanied with massively enhanced freedom of getting one's career obliterated.

Comment: If you seriously offend your boss or coworkers, yes, you can expect consequences.

Answer (score 12):

It's hard to answer without knowing the specifics of what they post. However, it could be very damaging if it comes out. There's a large amount of online mob mentality that has the potential to ruin anyone's life. It doesn't help that many news sites are more than happy to write a story about minor Internet drama, which often gets even more people to talk about it.

I can see two ways this could be damaging to your friend's graduate career:

1. Professors will want to protect their own reputation and might avoid working with your friend if they're seen as provocative or "bad" by others. Being someone's graduate adviser is an important relationship and some people will avoid associating themselves with your friend.
2. Some students might avoid taking classes from someone they see as "unsafe" or antagonistic. If they complain, your friend might not be given any TA positions by the school.

Could it be damaging to their post-graduate career? Certainly. There are countless articles about people who made one mistake or had a joke take out of context and now find it hard to find a job. Take a look at [this article](http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2015/feb/21/internet-shaming-lindsey-stone-jon-ronson) about a girl who took a "funny" picture at the Tomb of the Unknown Soldier:

> Life was inundated with emails demanding their jobs, so Lindsey was called into work. But she wasn’t allowed inside the building. Her boss met her in the car park and told her to hand over her keys. “Literally overnight, everything I knew and loved was gone,” Lindsey said. And that’s when she fell into a depression, became an insomniac, and barely left home for a year.

One bad Facebook joke and she loses her job. You also have "Donglegate," Michael Richards, Justine Sacco, etc. The Internet is a scary place.

Or maybe your friend never gets caught or no one ever cares and it all turns out fine. Who knows?